# MySQL convert timediff output to day, hour, minute, second format

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time) AS "total" FROM `metrics`;
```

which gives me:

```
116:12:10
```

meaning 116 hours, 12 minutes and 10 seconds.

Instead, I want it to say 4 days 20 hours, 12 minutes etc

Comment: I am not sure whether there is any inbuilt function for that or not, i think it can be done by applying simple mathematics ...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(
FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2010-01-06 08:46', '2010-01-01 12:30')) / 24), ' days ',
MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2010-01-06 08:46', '2010-01-01 12:30')), 24), ' hours ',
MINUTE(TIMEDIFF('2010-01-06 08:46', '2010-01-01 12:30')), ' minutes')
```

Use your end_time and start_time for the fixed datetime values in my example

As per the two comments below, this solution only works for date differences within 35 days. If you know there are more than 35 days between start and end, i.e. differences over a month, don't use it. Other answers here using TIMESTAMPDIFF will work.

Comment: @richard : your query will fail for long difference dates.read this http://www.microshell.com/database/mysql/getting-around-mysql-timediff-maximum-value-of-8385959/

Comment: This function will fail with theses inputs : SELECT CONCAT(
FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2010-03-06 08:46', '2010-01-01 12:30')) / 24), ' days ',
MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2010-03-06 08:46', '2010-01-01 12:30')), 24), ' hours ',
MINUTE(TIMEDIFF('2010-03-06 08:46', '2010-01-01 12:30')), ' minutes')

Answer (score 17):

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(
TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,'2001-01-01 00:00:00','2001-01-02 23:10:00') , ' dagen ',
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,'2001-01-01 00:00:00','2001-01-02 23:10:00'), 24), ' uren ',
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,'2001-01-01 00:00:00','2001-01-02 23:10:00'), 60), ' minuten '
)
```

Comment: Great alternative if you can't use `TIMEDIFF` due to the time difference being too large

Answer (score 4):

I used the answer given by **Bodgans**, but I added a condition to insert a 0 before quantities less than 10.

```
CONCAT(
  IF(FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) / 86400) < 10, '0', ''),    FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) / 86400), ' days ',
  IF(FLOOR((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) % 86400)/3600) < 10, '0', ''), FLOOR((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) % 86400)/3600), ' hours ',
  IF(FLOOR((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) % 3600)/60) < 10, '0', ''), FLOOR((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) % 3600)/60), ' minutes ',
  IF((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) % 60) < 10, '0', ''), (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) % 60),  ' seconds'
)
```

In that way, we can get a result as follows

> 09 days 10 hours 06 minutes 30 seconds

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
SELECT @s:='2016-03-01' started, @e:= '2018-04-21' ended, 
FLOOR((@ms:=TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,@s,@e))/12) yrs, (@ms%12) mns, 
@d:=TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,@s:=DATE_ADD(@s,INTERVAL @ms MONTH), @e) dys,
@hr:=TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,@s:=DATE_ADD(@s, INTERVAL @d DAY),@e) hrs,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,@hr,@s),@e) mins;
```

This will give you a breakdown from year, month, day, hour and minutes between two dates.

Hope it assists someone.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is

```
CONCAT(
  FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) / 86400), ' days ',
  FLOOR((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) % 86400)/3600), ' hours ',
  FLOOR((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) % 3600)/60), ' minutes ',
  (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) % 60),  ' seconds'
)
```

To show only relevant information you'd need to do a more complex version

```
IF(
  FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) / 86400) = 0,
  IF(
    FLOOR((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) % 86400)/3600) = 0,
    IF(
      FLOOR((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) % 3600)/60) = 0,
      CONCAT((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) % 60),  ' seconds'),
      CONCAT(
        FLOOR((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) % 3600)/60), ' minutes ',
        (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) % 60),  ' seconds'
      )
    ),
    CONCAT(
      FLOOR((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) % 86400)/3600), ' hours ',
      FLOOR((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) % 3600)/60), ' minutes ',
      (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) % 60),  ' seconds'
    )
  ),
  CONCAT(
    FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) / 86400), ' days ',
    FLOOR((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) % 86400)/3600), ' hours ',
    FLOOR((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) % 3600)/60), ' minutes ',
    (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDate, endDate) % 60),  ' seconds'
  )
)
```