# Format result from TIMEDIFF in days:hours:min:sec

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL convert timediff output to day, hour, minute, second format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279079/mysql-convert-timediff-output-to-day-hour-minute-second-format)

I have a simple query which calculates time difference between two datetime as below:

```
 SELECT TIMEDIFF( '2012-08-19 08:25:13', '2012-07-19 18:05:52' );
```

> Output: 734:19:21

The output is in hours:min:sec. However I want the output to be formatted as:

> days:hours:min:sec

How can I format the output?

Comment: Sounds like a job for your application, not a SQL query. SQL's job is to give your application the data, not format it pretty. I'd get the difference in seconds and format it at display time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(
   FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2012-08-05 09:56', '2012-08-02 11:20')) / 24), ' days, ',
   MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2012-08-05 09:56', '2012-08-02 11:20')), 24), ' hours, ',
   MINUTE(TIMEDIFF('2012-08-05 09:56', '2012-08-02 11:20')), ' minutes, ',
   SECOND(TIMEDIFF('2012-08-05 09:56', '2012-08-02 11:20')), ' seconds')
AS TimeDiff
```

[See this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfab1/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date_format(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2012-08-19 08:25:13' ) -
unix_timestamp('2012-07-19 18:05:52' )), '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

Comment: If the difference is less than 24 hours, the number of days should be 0, but `date_format` will not return you 0 as the day value. Basically, I think the issue is you are trying to have an *interval* interpreted as a *timestamp*.

Comment: SELECT date_format(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2012-08-20 18:25:13' ) -
unix_timestamp('2012-08-19 08:05:52' )), '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s');

result= 02.01.1970 12:19:21