# Calculate difference between two dates and convert this date to Days, Hours and Minutes left

Tags: javascript, php, sql, date

I have two given `SQL dates` and I need to calculate the difference (I believe this is done with the `diff method`) and afterwards convert this new date to days, hours and minutes left (a countdown).

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: So using MySQL? what's the relevance of the JavaScript tag?

Comment: What is the part causing you difficulty?  Also, are you attempting to do this with sql, php, or javascript?

Comment: @DanBracuk converting the new date to Days/Hours/minutes. Im doing this in PHP but I thought this would be done using javascript maybe..

Comment: Do it in MySQL? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279079/mysql-convert-timediff-output-to-day-hour-minute-second-format

Comment: Why not do it in the query using MySQL syntax. `DATEDIFF(date1,date2)` and `DATE_FORMAT(date,format)`

Comment: The difference between two dates yields a number, not a date.  Plus, if you want a countdown, have you considered javascript?  In fact, a google search on "javascript countdown" will lead you to code that's already been written.