# mysql & php - How to calculate total year of experience from multiple date range?

Tags: php, mysql, date-range

I want to calculate total experience year and month of each particular user id. user_id can be multiple in the table like the following. Here for user_id 14, the total experience range will be from 2010-01-03 to 2013-11-30 and the expected result will be 3 year 11 month.  How can I do it in either php or mysql?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279079/mysql-convert-timediff-output-to-day-hour-minute-second-format

Comment: If you want further help on top of what @jewelhuq has suggested you need to create an SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) with sample data and edit your question to  show expected output based on your sample data.

Comment: In mySQL the is a function datediff - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Is `exp_to` nullable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments are relevant but incomplete for your case.

If `exp_to` is not nullable:

```
select user_id, sum( datediff(exp_to, exp_from) +1 )
from experience
group by user_id;
```

Notes:

- don't forget `+1` in the sum, because for user 25 it would return 0, whereas we can decently consider the user worked 1 day
- for user 14, based on your screenshot, the total is 880 days: you'll have to calculate the number of months (with PHP, for example).

If `exp_to` is nullable (which makes sense if user is still working at the same position):

```
select user_id, sum( datediff( ifnull(exp_to, now()), exp_from) +1 )
from experience
group by user_id;
```

Comment: oh, that is what i am looking for. Thanks :)