# Sum all the previous work experiences (into months) where rows are dynamic (1 row for 1 experience) and different for each employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, datediff, ssms-2012

I have a table which stores work experience history of employees where each experience is stored as 1 row.

TblWorkExp :

```
--------------------------------------------------
ID      | ExperienceID |  From_Date | To_Date    |
--------------------------------------------------
EMP001  |      1       |  1-Jan-18  | 31-Dec-18  |
--------------------------------------------------
EMP001  |      2       |  1-Jan-19  | 31-May-19  |
--------------------------------------------------
EMP001  |      3       |  1-Jun-19  | 31-Dec-19  |
--------------------------------------------------
EMP002  |      1       |  1-Jan-19  | 28-Feb-19  |
--------------------------------------------------
EMP002  |      2       |  1-Apr-19  | 31-May-19  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

My Output should be

```
---------------------------
ID      | Total Experience|  
---------------------------
EMP001  |      24 Months  |  
---------------------------
EMP002  |      04 Months  | 
---------------------------
```

What I had done initially was calculating datediff months between
Min(ExperienceID) from_date and max(ExperienceID) to_date which would give me results if there are no gaps between jobs

```
Select ExpMin.ID, datediff(month,ExpMin.From_date ,ExpMax.To_Date) as 'Total Experience'
 from TblWorkExp ExpMin, TblWorkExp ExpMax 
where 
ExpMin.ID = ExpMax.ID and
ExpMin.From_date = (select min(a.From_date) from TblWorkExp a where ExpMin.ID = a.ID )and
ExpMax.To_date = (select Max(a.To_date) from TblWorkExp a where ExpMax.ID = a.ID )
```

It works fine when there are no gaps between jobs. I need my results like

```
---------------------------
ID      | Total Experience|  
---------------------------
EMP001  |      24 Months  |  
---------------------------
EMP002  |      04 Months  | 
---------------------------
```

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151815/mysql-php-how-to-calculate-total-year-of-experience-from-multiple-date-range/37152908

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your query.

```
select ID, sum(datediff(month, from_date, to_date)) As [Total Experience] from TblWorkExp 
group by ID
```

Comment: This is what i was going to suggest, A Datediff and group by will do the trick. As simple as that. Awesome @metal!!